# Trying to install socket.io of npm NodeJS

Tags: node.js, centos, npm

I'm trying to install socket.io of npm NodeJS, and I got those errors:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/-/socket.io-1.0.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/-/socket.io-client-1.0.6.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/has-binary-data/-/has-binary-data-0.1.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/nan/-/nan-0.3.2.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/component-inherit/-/component-inherit-0.0.3.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/callsite/-/callsite-1.0.0.tgz

> ws@0.4.31 install /home/admin/domains/{domain}.com/public_html/chat/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

I have centos 5.10.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please also add the command that you're typing in.  On the face of it it just likes a http error.  Have you tried `curl`ing the urls in the error log manually to see if you can get to them?

Comment: @JujharSingh I typed "npm install socket.io" and than I got those errors. I cant curl them because I dont know what realy it do with those links, I just want install socket.io. Thanks!